Correct usage of modals, "need to", and "may"
I want to just verify my usage of the following modals in these contexts as per the question given in the exam:
The options are to assign either "need to" or "may" to each sentence(to be used only once):
My answer:
You may answer any two of the following questions.
We need to try this new restaurant in town.
So, can anybody tell me if these modals are correct as is or should I
swap them with each other to form the correct sentences, basically just need justification for their usage in these sentences.
Justification for my answer:

usage of "need to" in a suggestive tone

usage of "may" as in telling a general instruction.



need to is not a modal verb. need to is have to=have an obligation to do something. may is just possibility.

If the first sentence is in a question paper, normally it is an imperative sentence - "Answer any one of the following:"* Your second sentence has many possibilities - "can, may,  must, ought to, should etc.

Both are grammatically correct.
May is a slightly ambiguous choice for an exam paper, as it carries a slight suggestion that you could answer only one question if you wanted to! I think it would be more usual to say You must answer any two (any being sufficient to give the element of choice).
Must and need to in the context of a suggestion are of course not meant literally; both carry the implication that it would be a very good idea.

Those two are the only options,either may or need to

So is the usage correct or do I need to swap them

@priyakulkarni "need to" can be used in the first sentence, but "may" doesn't sound right in the second. So I don't think you can swap them.

You didn't say that this was an exercise! I assumed you had used the tag 'exam questions' because the first one looks like instructions in a paper. As I said, must is the one I would find most natural. I don't know which the test setters are looking for. I agree with Barmar that may doesn 't fit the second one.

Thanks needed that only and I will remove the tag or edit the format heavily, sorry for the inconvenience
